# how to check if a value of a known index of an object found in another object exist

Tags: javascript, object

Lets say I have the following object

```
var myObject = {
 index1: {
    indexsub1: index1value1,
    indexsub2: index1value2,
 },
 index2: {
    indexsub1: index2value1,
    indexsub2: index2value2,
 },
 index3: {
    indexsub1: index3value1,
    indexsub2: index3value2,
 },
}
```

How can I check if there exist an indexsub1 in myObject where the value is x without knowing the index1, index2, and index3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myObject = {
 index1: {
    indexsub1: 1,
    indexsub2: 2,
 },
 index2: {
    indexsub1: 3,
    indexsub2: 4,
 },
 index3: {
    indexsub1: 5,
    indexsub2: 6,
 },
}

// key exists and value equal
console.log(
  Object.keys(myObject).some(key => myObject[key]['indexsub1'] === 1)
);

// key exists but value not equal
console.log(
  Object.keys(myObject).some(key => myObject[key]['indexsub1'] === 7)
);

// key doesn't exist
console.log(
  Object.keys(myObject).some(key => myObject[key]['indexsub7'] === 7)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myObject = {
  index1: {
    indexsub1: 1,
    indexsub2: 2,
  },
  index2: {
    indexsub1: 3,
    indexsub2: 4,
  },
  index3: {
    indexsub1: 5,
    indexsub2: 6,
  },
};

function hasKeyValue(key, value) {
  for (var prop in myObject) {
    if (myObject[prop][key] === value)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasKeyValue("indexsub1", 5));
console.log(hasKeyValue("indexsub1", 7));
```

Answer (score 1):

with `Object.keys()` you can get all keys of an object. This will produce an Array `['index1', 'index2', 'index3']`.

```
Object.keys(myObject)
```

now you can use this to access all sub-objects, and there check if the property `indexsub1` has a certain value:

```
const hasX = Object.keys(myObject).any(index => {
  const subObject = myObject[index];
  if (subObject.indexsub1 == 'x') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```